# broken pipe when installing NodeJS 16 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Trying to install NodeJS 16 on ubuntu 22.04.

Ran the official installation instructions:

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Got the following error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 128 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 218989 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.17.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (16.17.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.17.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.17.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Look like you are using MSI device?

Comment: Remove your old libnode-dev package 12.22.9 first

Comment: The error message indicates a packaging error, probably then suggesting that you are in fact installing some third-party hack, not the real `nodejs` package from the official sources. Voting to close as lacking basic debugging details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to overwrite \`/var/backups/infodir.bak', which is also in package x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546064/trying-to-overwrite-var-backups-infodir-bak-which-is-also-in-package-x)

Answer (score 4):

Various versions of Node.js are using a same file (one from `apt install`, one from manually download), which caused the conflict, resulting the error.

Remove your Node.js 12.22.9 first.

Comment: i do 

sudo apt remove nodejs  

aftar than install nodejs 

but don't work for me

Comment: @OmidPirdehi What you need may be `libnode-dev` and its dependents.

Comment: I have the same issue without that libnode-dev on my box. This is a weird one.

Comment: I had to remove ember as well to make it work for some reason.

Comment: I had to `sudo apt remove libnode-dev` and then `sudo apt autoremove` before the install worked.